Movie about a smart house that locks the family in?
Does anyone know what film this is? (Its NOT the disney one with Katey Segal)
I can only remember a few details from the film:

Its an American film.
Its a Thriller
Its from 80s - Early 90s
The father of the family built the house.
I remember the father was played by a well known actor.

I remember the main plot of the story being about the smart house (female computer) barricading the family in the house and the family have to try and escape.
Thats all i can remember. Anyone have any ideas?

Are you certain it was a theater film, instead of made for tv, or a tv show episode? There's twilight zone and outer limit episodes that match this

It was definitely a full length movie but it could have been made for tv only.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please [edit] in any details you know: You're very short on plot here... do you remember anything else about the story? You tag it as "thriller" is that the case? if so, include it in your question.

Thats it... damn you're good. Ty ty ty

I was not aware that Timothy Busfield was that "well-known" of an actor.... nonetheless, question was answered :)

I got confused with the actor :/

No worries, glad your question was answered :)
